# react native dynamically change ListView from SQLite

Tags: listview, react-native

I want to re render the List view after getting result form database. I tried almost all the possible ways from google but it's not working. The records from data base are fetching correctly but list view is not updating. Please find my code below. I want to live search data from database & show them in ListView

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, H3,Item,Input, ListItem, Button, Icon, Footer, FooterTab, Left, Right, Body } from 'native-base';

import { openDrawer } from '../../actions/drawer';
import styles from './styles';

class Dictionary extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    openDrawer: React.PropTypes.func,
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
        isLoading: false,
    }
  }
  searchMatchingWords(keyWord) {
    if(keyWord.length > 0) {
      var temp = [];
      db.executeSql("SELECT `English` FROM `dictionary`  WHERE `English` LIKE '"+keyWord+"%' ORDER BY  `English` ASC LIMIT 0, 30", [], function(results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
            }
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(temp),
            });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>

        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent onPress={this.props.openDrawer}>
              <Icon name="ios-menu" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Search Words</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <Header searchBar rounded>
          <Item>
            <Icon active name="search" />
            <Input placeholder="Search" onChangeText={(text) => this.searchMatchingWords(text)}/>
            <Icon active name="bookmark" />
          </Item>
          <Button transparent>
            <Text>Search</Text>
          </Button>
        </Header>

        <Content>
            <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
              <ListView
                enableEmptySections={true}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(rowData) =>
                  <ListItem>
                    <Text>{rowData.English}</Text>
                    <Right><Icon name="arrow-forward" /></Right>
                  </ListItem>
                }/>
            </View>
        </Content>

      </Container>
    );
  }
}

function bindAction(dispatch) {
  return {
    openDrawer: () => dispatch(openDrawer()),
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  navigation: state.cardNavigation,
  themeState: state.drawer.themeState,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(Dictionary);
```

Comment: add this after var temp = []; temp = this.state.ds.slice();, chekc it n let me know

Comment: its not working @NiteshMishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. There is no issue with react native setState. The problem was with

> this

operator.

```js
if(keyWord.length > 0) {
      var temp = [];
      var self = this;
      db.executeSql("SELECT `English` FROM `dictionary`  WHERE `English` LIKE '"+keyWord+"%' ORDER BY  `English` ASC LIMIT 0, 30", [], function(results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
            }
            self.setState({
                dataSource: self.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(temp),
            });
      });
    }
```